# How does function as a parameter to another function work in PHP?

Tags: php, function

The following code show some function called as parameter to another function:

```
$somevar = count(substr(time(),0,10));
echo $somevar;
```

Does the innermost function gets executed first?

Comment: The parameters have to be resolved for them to be available to be passed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The above code translates to the following:

```
$timestamp = time();
$first_ten_chars = substr($timestamp ,0 , 10);
$somevar = count($first_ten_chars);
```

However, the code doesn't really make much sense. `time()` returns a Unix timestamp, and it will have (most likely have) 10 characters (unless you're talking about a date that's 273+ years from now), so the `substr()` function will just return the entire timestamp. `count()` counts the number of elements in an array / object, and since you're passing a string, it will always return `1`.

If you state what you're trying to do, I may be able to suggest the correct way of doing it.

Comment: it's odd that someone would plan for the future by only getting the first 10 digits of time. By the time the string length of `time()` is 11 digits the date will be: `11/20/2286 12:46:40`

Comment: @SamuelCook: It's the same as 273 years: `(2013 + 273 = 2286)` :)